# Monotouch UICalendar Store Events In Custom DB

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, icalendar

I'm using https://github.com/Clancey/UICalendar

I want to store the events that it adds as a row in my custom db table. However, I don't currently see that the UICalendar library actually exposes any events to do this. What is the best way to store events added using UICalendar into a custom db? Or at least get access to the event?

Any help extremely appreciated!

[EDIT]

Looks like I need to use `EKEvent` to find the currently saved value. How would I get the values from the event currently being triggered to save from my application?

Comment: Why don't you just modify UICalendar to raise an event when an item is saved?  It should be simple to do, and you could submit it back to the author for inclusion in the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like UICalendar is only visual component. You should to handle store/load event via your own code. For example, via SQLite-net ORM library (http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/).

If you want to use UICalendar to show/edit event in systemt calendar, use `EKEvent` and other `EventKit` framework classes to reach that information.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm doing. I'm using that exact ORM library. I need to know how to find out when the event was saved and what with what values.

Comment: You mean sample app that is bundled with component sources? If so, you can see at UICalendar-master/UICalendar/CalendarViews.cs:258 method portriatNavBar(), in which app creates _rightButton with delegate event handler. In that handler app using `EKEventEditViewController`, which is part of `EventKit`. So you can use `addController.Completed` event handler for your purpose.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did LOL. I imported the code into my project because I have quite a few changes to make. But, yeah I made the changes there and that's working out pretty well so far. I will post code soon

Comment: Thanks for the help. I posted some sample code below to help people with more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I actually imported the UICalendar Project into my project and made the changes to `CalendarViews.cs` line `258` which is where this fun begins.

Below you can see exactly what I did to intercept the event so that they could associate some custom data that I need to store along with the event for the application. Basically this will intercept the event and present a `DVC` or `DialogViewController` to handle some extra user interaction. From here you can save stuff accordingly.

```
        private void portriatNavBar ()
        {
            //  _leftButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Calendars", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, HandlePreviousDayTouch);
            NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = _orgLefButton;
            NavigationItem.Title = "Calendar";
            _rightButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, delegate {
                addController = new EKEventEditViewController ();   
                // set the addController's event store to the current event store.
                addController.EventStore = Util.MyEventStore;
                addController.Event = EKEvent.FromStore(Util.MyEventStore);
                addController.Event.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
                addController.Event.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

                addController.Completed += delegate(object theSender, EKEventEditEventArgs eva) {
                    switch (eva.Action)
                    {
                        case EKEventEditViewAction.Canceled :
                        case EKEventEditViewAction.Deleted :
                        case EKEventEditViewAction.Saved:
                        this.NavigationController.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);

                        break;
                    }
                };

                // Going to create a precursor to actually displaying the creation of a calendar event so we can grab everything correctly
                RootElement _ctRoot = new RootElement ("Task Details") {
                    new Section () {
                        new RootElement ("Clients") {
                            AppSpecificNamespace.TaskController.GetClientsForCalendar ()
                        },
                        new RootElement ("Task Types") {
                            AppSpecificNamespace.TaskController.GetTypesForCalendar ()
                        }
                    },
                    new Section () {
                        new StyledStringElement ("Continue", delegate {
                            this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated (true);
                            this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController (addController, true);
                        }) { Alignment = UITextAlignment.Center, TextColor = UIColor.Blue }
                    }
                };
                DialogViewController AppSpecificDVC = new DialogViewController (_ctRoot);
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController (AppSpecificDVC, true);
                //this.NavigationController.PresentViewController (AppSpecificDVC, true, null);
            });

            NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = _rightButton;
        }
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: It's a good practice to post final answer for question. Thus, people with exactly the same question could use your solution. Cheers for that!